# Match Excel Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have 2 spreadsheets that should be the same however they are not. They each have an ID column. I want to see what ID's are not on one spreadsheet but are on the other. For example in the screenshot Loc_ID = 0000 I need to check if this is on the other spreadsheet. What is the best way of doing this? And finding a list of the ideas that do not match. 
[image]

I've tried doing =IF(E904=J904,"Match","fALSE") however this is simply for that column and they don't match up so this will not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Vlookup function:

=VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE).

Comment: H and V lookup formula's in excel are superb, however they can get very slow on large datasets. If you suffer from really poor performance, consider switching to using a database and joins which will perform much better.

Comment: I've given this a go however just get #REF. Not quite sure why. I am trying this: =IF(VLOOKUP(B2,F2:F40,2,FALSE)="Located","Not Found")